# Display simple image in my jsp-generate page

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

This question may betray my total lack of understanding, so be it, I guess. Trying the following code to display an image once the JSP page is running on Tomcat. Note, it's the  tag that isn't working for me:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>George Brown GeoQuest - Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
<img alt="logo" src="WebContent/GBGeoQuestLogo.gif">

</br>
<h1>Welcome, GB Geoquest Team!</h1>
<form action="/Lab4">
    <label>Team Name:
        <input type="text" name="name">
    </label><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

All I get is the blue image question-mark symbol in the top left instead of my image. Link should be viewable here: http://postimage.org/image/drnl831pz/

Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to confirm that the image file is in the war file.  Once you're sure it's there try removing the "WebContent" from the url in the JSP

Comment: I'm not even sure what a war file is. I'm looking it up but answers like "packaged web app directory" don't yet mean anything to me. My image file is (in this case) Lab4/WebContent folder. I don't know what to look for or how to get it in there. Thanks for the answer so far, though!

Answer (score 0):

The value of the src-attribute is missing the context of the application. Now the hostname is used as the context root, so browser uses the wrong url, e.g. `http://localhost:8080/WebContent/GBGeoQuestLogo.gif`

Add the context root to the src attribute and the image will be loaded, assuming 1) it's inside the war 2) it's located in WebContent-directory in the war:

src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/WebContent/GBGeoQuestLogo.gif"

Comment: I'm not even sure what a war file is. I'm looking it up but answers like "packaged web app directory" don't yet mean anything to me. My image file is (in this case) Lab4/WebContent folder. I don't know what to look for or how to get it in there. Thanks for the answers so far, though!

Comment: WAR is a package format. One packages a java web application in to a WAR in order to run it in a container, e.g. Tomcat.

You don't necessary need a war to run a java webapp though. I assume your application is located directly in the webapps-directory of Tomcat?

The solution is still the same, use the JSP el expression ${pageContext.request.contextPath} as a prefix in the src-attribute value and it should work.

Look at the generated HTML and you'll see the correct context. Then adjust the rest of the path to correct one if necessary.

Comment: My application is running from my documents folder, not the webapps folder in Tomcat. Does that make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

I think your context path is Lab4/WebContent and your image is in WebContent. So in this case you can get image by,

```
src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/GBGeoQuestLogo.gif"
```

It will search image in WebContent because your Context path is Lab4/WebContent. If still have problem than in browser View Pagesource and verify the Image path

Thank you

Comment: Crap, this still isn't working. In Page Source in Chrome, my image path is <img alt="logo" src="/Lab4/GBGeoQuestLogo.gif"> In Eclipse, I also then get red squigglies with messages like "No exception of type JspException can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable" once I paste in the recommended text, though the program still runs/compiles.